# How to change line endings in Wordpress theme editor?

Tags: wordpress, newline

My boss sometimes edits files using the Wordpress Admin theme editor. Upon saving a file, Wordpress changes all of the line endings from `\n` to `\r\n`.

Is there anyway to get it to save the files with `\n` ?

Comment: one solution might be to tell your boss to stop doing it wrong. Mileage may vary.

Comment: That's not really a solution. He needs a "noob" method of editing the files easily.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre) to get the content before it hits the database and then do a regex [search and replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to remove the unwanted line ending.

```
// untested
$content = str_replace('\r\n', '\n', $content);
```